# Get caret offset in content editable div to include HTML offset

Tags: javascript

I am trying to to get the get the caret offest inside a content editable div that includes the  offset of the HTML.

For example:

```
<div contenteditable=true>
   hello &nbsp;|(caret is here)
</div>
```

In the above example the caret offset should be **5** ("hello")  **+** **1**(" ") **+** **6**("`&nbsp;`") **= 12**

Instead I am getting `offset=7` as `&nbsp;` is being converted to a space and counted as 1.

See my code below:

```
var range1 = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0),
range2 = range1.cloneRange();
range2.selectNodeContents(target);
range2.setEnd(range1.endContainer, range1.endOffset);
return range2.toString().length;
```

**Any help would be appreciated!**

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the HTML of the div, not the text. For this example I've added a ID of `special_div` to the div, obviously you can change the character in the `indexOf` to anything you'd like.

HTML

```
<div id="special_div" contenteditable=true>
hello &nbsp;|(caret is here)
</div>
```

Javascript

```
document.getElementById('special_div').innerHTML.indexOf('|');
```

JQuery

```
$('#special_div').html().indexOf('|');
```